# ARCore Gesture Rotation Issue

Tags: java, android, arcore, game-development

I am working on an AR android game that lets the user "flick" the screen to move a ball in the world. I managed to create the gesture using Java (would prefer to use AR libraries) and ran into the problem that by walking to a different side of the sphere the "flick" motion stayed the same. I need the ball to move up when the player flicks up based on rotation of the camera. 
For example, If I flick up on the screen I want the ball to move forward and it does. If I walk around to the left side of the ball and flick up the ball moves left (the previous forward) when it should also move forwards.

Thank you for any help you can give.